# Adding multiple elements to an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have following code:

```
var keyword = "foo";
var business_type = "bakery";
var int = "1";
var text = "bar";
keywords[keyword] = {business_type : {int : { 0 : text}}};
```

The keywords Object already exists and has content. So I just want to add something to it.
I want the output to be an object like this:

```
var keywords = {"foo" : {"bakery" : { "1" : { 0 : "bar"}}}};
```

(not sure if my depiction of the output is correct, but I think you will get the point)
But I get an output like this

```
var keywords = {"foo" : {"business_type" : { "int" : { 0 : "bar"}}}};
```

So I guess the code thinks my key variables (business_type, int) are strings. How is it possible to take the variables value instead of the string ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp


int is reserved word.

Use for example
var i = "1";
instead  
var int = "1";

Comment: change your variable name from int to something else

Comment: @Kaiser: No, it isn't. [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1), [ES6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reserved-words). Quoting [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) is not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keywords[keyword][business_type][int] = {0:text};
```

Or the safer way

```
keywords[keyword] = {};
keywords[keyword][business_type] = {};
keywords[keyword][business_type][int] = {0:text};
```

You can do either way.

Comment: Undefined everywhere, very poor answer here.

Comment: @ShanShan: This works correctly, but presupposes some knowledge.

Comment: @Amadan It was edited, I was commenting first version: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34329037/1

Comment: Too bad you took out the `{[...]: ...}` notation... it was informative.

Comment: @Amadan I didnt remove it, just got confused while editing.

Comment: the `keywords[keyword] = {[business_type] : {[int] : { 0 : text}}};` worked fine for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the array notation and initialize each level of the object:

```js
var keyword = "foo";
var business_type = "bakery";
var int = "1";
var text = "bar";

var keywords = {};
keywords[keyword] = {};
keywords[keyword][business_type] = {};
keywords[keyword][business_type][int] = { 0: text };

var out = JSON.stringify(keywords, null, 3);
console.log(out);
document.write('<pre>' + out + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use variables to declare properties of objects like you do. Try using brackets:

```
keywords[keyword] = {[business_type] : {[int] : { 0 : text}}};
```

or write properties explicitly:

```
keywords[keyword] = {"bakery" : {"1" : { 0 : text}}};
```